# AngularJS - $broadcast message to controllers generates duplicate notifications

Tags: javascript, events, angularjs, angularjs-scope, broadcast

In my AngularJs and phonegap/cordova application I listen for the back button event.  I then broadcast this to certain controllers within my *app.js*:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('backButton');
    }, false);
}, false);
```

In certain views I want to listen to this so that I can inform the user that they will be quitting the app and give them the option to continue or not.

So there are two controls, lobby and game.

When a user clicks back in the lobby they should see a notification telling them they will be quitting the app:

```
$rootScope.$on('backButton', function(event){

    $window.navigator.notification.confirm(
        'Are you sure you want to exit app?',       // message
        $scope.exitApp,                             // callback to invoke
        'APP',                                  // title
        ['OK', 'Cancel']                            // button labels
    );
```

And if they hit OK they are logged out from the app and re-directed to the login screen.

When they are in the game view they should be informed they will be quitting their game and then redirected to the lobby:

```
$rootScope.$on('backButton', function(event){
    $window.navigator.notification.confirm(
        'Are you sure you want to quit your game?',     // message
        $scope.quitGame,                                // callback to invoke
        'GAME',                                     // title
        ['OK', 'Cancel']                                // button labels
    );
});
```

The issue I am seeing is that when I am in the game I see both notifications when I click the back button.  One for the game which is correct but then an additional one for the lobby which is not needed.

So this is not really a defect, this is how it should work but being relatively new to Angular I am not sure of best approach as broadcast seems inappropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

`$rootScope.$broadcast` is as the method implies a broadcasting mechanism. Whatever listeners are attach will get fired on broadcast, irrespective of where they are declared.

To fix it, you would have to determine first whether the controller related to `lobby` should be in fact be loaded or not when `game` controller is loaded. If the views for game and lobby are different and are not present in the same parent view, then lobby controller should not remain loaded when you are on game view. This is a typical memory leak.

In case both of them should be present, then in your handling methods `on` you need to decide based on context which event handler to fire. You can make this decision using `$route` or `$location` service, which provide the current url\view (ng-view) in use.

Comment: Hi, yes I used $location.path() method as per your suggestion.

Both controllers do not need to be loaded at the same time.

Comment: Then you should not require any check to be performed. This could be memory leak issue.

Comment: Not sure what is going on but the i commented out the board listener, checked that the back button event listener was only being bound once but still i get repeat notifications.  So if i exit the app one time, there will be two notifications, then if i exit again, three notifications and so on.

That would point to the event listener being re-bound but it clearly is not!